# Unexpected Union behaviour

Tags: c, floating-point, double, output, unions

The code below outputs different numbers each time ..
apples.num prints 2 which is correct, and apples.weight prints different numbers each time, it once even printed out "nan", and I don't know why is this happening ..
The really strange thing is that the double (apples.volume) prints out 2.0 ..
Can anybody explain things to me ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    short num;
    float weight;
    double volume;
} Count;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Count apples;
    apples.num = 2;

    printf("Num: %d\nWeight: %f\nVolume: %f\n", apples.num, apples.weight, apples.volume);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't expect undefined behaviour to be defined.

Comment: You only set the `short` part of that union to some value. The rest will contain random data on each re-run.

Comment: So what is a boy suppose to do? Just pick the weight of you apple out of the air

Comment: Hmm, it actually seems C is much more lax on this: *If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6.* and *When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members
take unspecified values.*

Comment: There happens no conversion, your title is deceiving. Unions merely define a collected type which has the size of the largest element inside, and is responsible to hold only one of them at once. You may think of it as a field that you fill with encoding. You once use the encoding `int` and fill it with `2`; you mar decode it with `int` again, but don't expect it to make sense when you use something else to decode it.

Comment: @Jongware Sooo .. a union has only one member that is useful for each variable, so for apples, I'd use apple.num, for drinks, drink.volume, etc. Then, how do I set the wanted representation for each variable, and not use the others, or at least generate a warning if I try to ?

Comment: @AmrAyman, no in the contrary, members of `union`s share the representation and interpret it differently.

Comment: There is no standard data type in C that contains "the same meaning in other representations". You cannot express all possible float values as integer, and neither the reverse. (If you could, one of the two types would be obsolete.)

Comment: @JensGustedt So, how do I define the **main** representation for a single union variable ?

Comment: @AmrAyman : No.  A union simply allows different types to be stored in the same variable. 2.0f has a different bit pattern to 2 - the union does not magically change the bit pattern depending on which member you access.  Moreover short, float and double each have a different number of bits.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks, but I still can't really differentiate between structs and unions, please explain that ..

Comment: @chris strict aliasing still applies (6.5/7)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I figured there was still some problem like that. I'm just surprised because I'm pretty sure C++ has a lot of undefined behaviour around not reading the last written member.

Comment: @AmrAyman : Perhaps then you should be asking another question.  The comments section is not a discussion forum.  A `struct` contains all its members all the time in separate memory spaces.  A Union contains one of it's members at a time in a single shared memory space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you don't quite understand what a union is. The members of a union are overlapping values (in other words, the three members of a `Count` union **share the same space**).

Assuming, just for the sake of demonstration, a `short` is 16 bits (2 bytes), a `float` is 32 bits (4 bytes) and a `double` is 64 bits (8 bytes), then the union is 8 bytes in size. In little-endian format, the `num` member refers to the first 2 bytes, the `weight` member refers to the first 4 bytes (including the 2 bytes of `num`) and the volume member refers to the full 8 bytes (including the 2 bytes of `num` and the four bytes of `weight`).

Initially, your union contains garbage, i.e. some unknown bit pattern, let's display it like this (in hex):

```
GG GG GG GG GG GG GG GG   // GG stands for garbage, i.e. unknown bit patterns
```

If you set `num` to 2, then the first two bytes are `0x02` `0x00`, but the other bytes are still garbage:

```
02 00 GG GG GG GG GG GG
```

If you read `weight`, you are simply reading the first four bytes, interpreted as a `float`, so the `float` contains the bytes

```
02 00 GG GG
```

Since floating point values have a totally different format as integral types like `short`, you can't predict what those bytes (i.e. that particular bit pattern) represent. They do not represent the floating point value 2.0f, which is what you probably want. Actually, the "more significant" part of a `float` is stored in the upper bytes, i.e. in the "garbage" part of `weight`, so it can be almost anything, including a `NaN`, `+infinity`, `-infinity`, etc.

Similarly, if you read `volume`, you have a `double` that consists of the bytes

```
02 00 GG GG GG GG GG GG
```

and that does not necessarily represent 2.0 either (although, by chance, it MAY come very close, if by coincidence the right bits are set at the right places, and if the low bits are rounded away when you display such a value).

Unions are not meant to do a proper conversion from `int` to `float` or `double`. They are merely meant to be able to store different kinds of values to the same type, and reading from *another* member as you set simply means you are **reinterpreting** a number of bits that are present in the union as something completely different. You are not **converting**.

So how do you convert? It is quite simple and does not require a union:

```
short num = 2;
float weight = num; // the compiler inserts code that performs a conversion to float
double volume = num; // the compiler inserts code that performs a conversion to double
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the bits that have been set are the least significant 16 bits of the significand. The bits that control whether you have a NaN, Infinity, large finite, tiny finite, positive, negative etc. remain garbage.

Comment: I could do that, but I am not sure if mentioning the terms `exponent`, `significand`, etc. would not confuse the reader more than it helps him. He just has to know that floating point values have a different format.

Comment: I phrased my comment in terms I thought you would understand. You are doing a great job of expressing information in more basic terms. Meanwhile, has anyone actually said how to correctly convert an integer value to the corresponding float or double value?

Comment: @Patricia: no, I don't think so. I'll add it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis so, when I do this: `apples = {0};`, that defaults the whole 8 bytes to 0 ?

Comment: @AmrAyman: note that if you set one of the members of a union, you are overwriting (or partly overwriting) the other members, i.e. you can only use one of the members and should not access the others. If you need to store `num`, `weight` and `volume` separately, you should use a `struct` to keep them together.

Answer (score 2):

If you access a union via the "wrong" member (i.e. a member other than the one it was assigned  through), the result will depend on the semantics of the particular bit pattern for that type.  Where the assigned type has a smaller bit-width that he accessed type, some of those bits will be undefined.

Comment: @AmrAyman : I am not sure what you mean.  I suspect that what you actually need is a type cast.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing uninitialized data. It will provide undefined behavior (ie: unknown values in this case). [You also likely mean to use a `struct` instead of a `union`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346536/difference-between-a-structure-and-a-union-in-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    short num;
    float weight;
    double volume;
} Count;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Count apples = { 0 };
    apples.num = 2;

    printf("Num: %d\nWeight: %f\nVolume: %f\n", apples.num, apples.weight, apples.volume);
    return 0;
}
```

Initialize the union by either zeroing it out, or setting the largest member to a value. Even if you set the largest member, the other values might not even make sense. [This is commonly used for creating a byte/word/nibble/long-word data type and making the individual bits accessible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005349/define-union-that-can-access-bits-nibbles-bytes)

Comment: In all fairness, this is still not an *int to float conversion*, as the OP appears to think it is.

Comment: He could always do something like `apples.weight=1.0f` and checking for validity.